# Ошибка python.exe при сохранении .exe

Tags: python, pip, exe

При попытке сохранить `.exe` появляется ошибка:

```
[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.1 -> 22.2.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 2):

Это не ошибка, просто сегодня вышла новая версия `pip`, и чтобы ее обновить, напишите эту команду.
Для `Windows`:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Для `Linux`:

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```